# I need to match the unique value of rows from one dataset to the columns matching in another dataset and provide the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is the dataframe example where id is the index

df:

| id | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | False | NA |
| 2 | True | False | NA |
| 3 | False | True | True |

df2:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | NA | True |
| False | True | False | False |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | True | True | True |
| False | True | True | True |

Output:

Here we are matching the unique row if the id of df matches with the columns of df2 and has true
values in df2 columns then sum it per id of df and provide the data frame of the same index and ignoring d column in df2

| id | A | B | C | Sum of matched true values in columns of df2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | False | NA | 0 |
| 2 | True | False | NA | 2 |
| 3 | False | True | True | 6 |

match_df = try_df.merge(df, on= list_new , how='outer',suffixes=('', '_y'))
match_df.drop(match_df.filter(regex='_y$').columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
df_grouped = match_df.groupby('CIS Sub Controls')[list_new].agg(['sum', 'count'])
df_final = pd.concat([df_grouped['col1']['sum'], df_grouped['col2']['sum'], df_grouped['col3']['sum'], df_grouped['col4']['sum'], df_grouped['col1']['count'], df_grouped['col2']['count'], df_grouped['col3']['count'], df_grouped['col4']['count']], axis=1).join(df_grouped.index)

This is not how it goes

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
cols = df1.columns.intersection(df2.columns)

out = (df1.merge(df2[cols].value_counts(dropna=False).reset_index(name='sum'),
                 how='left')
          .fillna({'sum': 0}, downcast='infer')
      )
```

Output:

```
   id      A      B     C  sum
0   1  False  False   NaN    0
1   2   True  False   NaN    1
2   3  False   True  True    6
```